# ubuntu freezes on GPU(Nvideo) use

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, system, fan

I have been getting weird issues lately, everything seems fine since I installed Ubuntu, but there couple of issues happening, mainly when my system use GPU, it freezes completely, and there is also a loud fan that keeps coming out at that time, and when I inspect my System monitor, RAM is off-course getting consumed in its extent, previously it used to happened during browsing but I have disabled hardware acceleration on MOZILLA as well,

Any suggestion on how to resolve this issue, I am currently working on a project that also uses GPU in some way so it's getting difficult to run that.

Thanks in Advance

GPU: `NVIDIA GTX 1650`

OS: `20.04.3 LTS`

Comment: Have you installed Nvidia drivers and disabled Secure Boot?

Comment: i have disable secure boot since previously it used to give me issues with 3rd party drivers @ChanganAuto

Comment: Right, that's something. Now, what version of the Nvidia drivers have you installed?

Comment: `NVIDIA-SMI 470.86       Driver Version: 470.86       CUDA Version: 11.4 `

Comment: It is indeed the recommended version for your hardware. I suggest updating UEFI before anything else. Also Please always [edit] the question to add new information.

Comment: it is but i am not sure whether it has to do with driver version ,@someone